# inserting android data in mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

php code: when i insert the data into SQL database itc come like this. Can you tell me why data is not inserting in the database. In the database its insert 0000-00-00 (for date) and 00:00:00.0000 (for time). Can you please help me out

```
<?php
session_start();
$btnSelectDate=$_POST['btnSelectDate'];
$btnSelectTime=$_POST['btnSelectTime'];

$db = 'event';
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("not connected");  
mysql_select_db($db, $conn) or die("could not find database"); 
$query = "INSERT INTO date_time(btnSelectTime, btnSelectDate)
VALUES('$btnSelectTime', '$btnSelectDate')";  

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : "  
. mysql_error());  

if(mysql_num_rows($result))  

echo 1;  // for correct login response  
else  
echo 0; // for incorrect login response  
?>
```

Here is my android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

Button btnSelectDate,btnSelectTime,done;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=1;
// variables to save user selected date and time
public  int year,month,day,hour,minute;  
// declare  the variables to Show/Set the date and time when Time and  
Date Picker Dialog first appears
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay,mHour,mMinute;

// constructor

public MainActivity()
{
// Assign current Date and Time Values to Variables
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// get the references of buttons

btnSelectDate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectDate);
btnSelectTime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectTime);
done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
// Set ClickListener on btnSelectDate
btnSelectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
// Show the DatePickerDialog
showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);


}
});

// Set ClickListener on btnSelectTime
btnSelectTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
// Show the TimePickerDialog
showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
}});

done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();
}});}

public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String resresult=null;
try {

resresult = postText();

} catch (NullPointerException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return resresult;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}


}


private String postText(){

String responseStr=null;
try{

String postReceiverUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/a/insert4.php";

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();


entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);


entityBuilder.addTextBody("btnSelectDate",    
btnSelectDate.getText().toString());
entityBuilder.addTextBody("btnSelectTime", 
btnSelectTime.getText().toString());


HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
post.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);       


HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

if (resEntity != null) {

responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
//Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);

}

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

return responseStr;
}

// Register  DatePickerDialog listener
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
// the callback received when the user "sets" the Date in the 
DatePickerDialog
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yearSelected,
int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
year = yearSelected;
month = monthOfYear;
day = dayOfMonth;
// Set the Selected Date in Select date Button
btnSelectDate.setText("Date selected : "+day+"-"+month+"-"+year);
}};

// Register  TimePickerDialog listener                
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
// the callback received when the user "sets" the TimePickerDialog in   
the dialog
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int min) {
hour = hourOfDay;
minute = min;
// Set the Selected Date in Select date Button
btnSelectTime.setText("Time selected :"+hour+"-"+minute);
}};
// Method automatically gets Called when you call showDialog()  method
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
switch (id) {
case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
// create a new DatePickerDialog with values you want to show
return new DatePickerDialog(this,mDateSetListener,mYear, mMonth, mDay);
// create a new TimePickerDialog with values you want to show
case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
return new TimePickerDialog(this,
mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);}return null;}}
```

Comment: How this php and android communicates? I can not see any android codes

Comment: Write the contents of the $_POST array to a log file and post it here, alongside your android code

Comment: Please use one of mysqli_* or PDO: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp To insert a date in a database it has to be in the correct format, for example datetime 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

Comment: I did not add android code here.

Comment: You have a serious security hole in your code here - SQL injection. Please make sure it is fixed before you go live! If you want assistance about the immediate problem, please let us see an example query. I expect you've formatted the date incorrectly for MySQL, and so it defaults to all zeroes.

Comment: I have added the android code here. Please help me

Comment: I really need your suggestion. Can you guys help me out